# User Class In OOP

Tags: class, oop

I was started my learing in OOP and I make a class but I have a problem now. This is my little code:

```
class User {

    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $city;

    public function setDate($setName, $setAge, $setCity) 
    {
        $this->name = $setName;
        $this->age = $setAge;
        $this->city = $setCity;
    }

    public function pullDate()
    {
        return $this->name;
        return $this->age;
        return $this->city;
    }

}

$newUser = new User;
$newUser->setDate('Adrian', '23', 'Poland');
echo $newUser->pullDate();
```

And when I get variable by `echo $newUser->pullDate();` in response recerive only 'Adrian' ... How I can fix it?

Thanks for help!

Comment: Please edit your question and include tag for language you are using.

Comment: It's not clear what language this is - but I would assume the first return statement returns from the function so never gets to the other two data items you want

Comment: You can not return more than one object or value!, instead of return multiple create an object of class and return it as object.

Answer (score 1):

A function can only return a single value. Placing multiple `return` statements in a row does not make any sense, the function will always return after the first such statement. Instead you have to *combine* the values, for example by creating an array out of them.

Take a look at this modified version, assuming that you are using `php`:

```
<?php 
class User {

    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $city;

    public function setDate($setName, $setAge, $setCity) 
    {
        $this->name = $setName;
        $this->age = $setAge;
        $this->city = $setCity;
    }

    public function pullDate() {
        return [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'age' => $this->age,
            'city' => $this->city
        ];
    }
}

$newUser = new User;
$newUser->setDate('Adrian', '23', 'Poland');
$userValues = $newUser->pullDate();
echo sprintf(
    "Name: %s, Age: %s, City: %s\n",
    $userValues['name'],
    $userValues['age'],
    $userValues['city']
);
```

An alternative would be to implement separate "getters" for each property:

```
class User {
    // ...
    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }
    public function getAge() {
        return $this->age;
    }
    public function getCity() {
        return $this->city;
    }
    // ...
}
```

And then get the attributes one by one, just as desired, for example by doing:

```
echo sprintf(
    "Name: %s, Age: %s, City: %s\n",
    $newUser->getName(),
    $newUser->getAge(),
    $newUser->getCity()
);
```

Comment: Thanks for help! Previously i wrote getName, getAge, getCity but I thought it would be better to do it in one function.

Comment: As demonstrated, both is possible. Classical "getters" are a well known pattern which gives a lotof freedom especially for later modifications. But sometimes an (additional) combined method comes in handy too ;-)